# How to make a parametrized url with struts2 tags (eg. for setting as the form action url)

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

My jsp header file is:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<%
    String path = request.getContextPath();
    String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://"
            + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
            + path + "/";
%>
```

I want to make the form action url based on the `basePath`. I tried different tags but it didn't work! `<%=basePath%>` doesn't work; maybe because struts2 tags are rendered first.
And whatever I do try and error with `#, %, {` or property tag I can't make it work!
for example `<s:form name="searchItem" action="%{basePath + '/AdvancedSearch.action'}">` was one of the unsuccessful endeavors!

I just could make it work with a dirty hack:

```
<s:set var="searchUrl"><%=basePath%>AdvancedSearch.action</s:set>
<form name="searchForm" method="get" class="searchform" action="%{searchUrl}">
```

But I hope that there would be a better hack to let me eliminate the `<s:set>` tag line!

Comment: Why would you do it like this when there's a tag that does it all for you?

Comment: What is that tag? property tag doesn't work inside the <s:form> tag.

Comment: I don't even understand why you're not just using the form tag.

Comment: I use <form> tag when I don't need the table structure of the s:form or I find it problematic and I use <s:form> when I need that structure.

Comment: And what do you need here that s:form doesn't provide? Without knowing what you're even trying to do, helping is difficult.

Comment: the last <form> I have used can be easily replaced with a <s:form> and  it is not the case I could have copied other examples which use <s:form>. This is form not s:form because it is easier! In fact the struts tags inside <s:form> is problematic. I can't have <s:form action="<property value="sth" />" />

Comment: In fact I'd like to use sth like <%=basePath%>+'AdvancedSearch.action' in the s:form action attribute, but it is not allowed and results to exception!

Comment: @user1892555, struts2 will construct the url for the form just set the namespace and action attributes accordingly. If you need to construct urls in general you can use the s:url tag, to add parameters use the s:param tag.

Comment: ahhhhh! I wonder what to tell, @Quaternion ! Thanks a lot! I did not know it! What an idiot I am!

Answer (score 0):

As @Quaternion has told:

> struts2 will construct the url for the form just set the namespace and
>   action attributes accordingly. If you need to construct urls in
>   general you can use the s:url tag, to add parameters use the s:param
>   tag.

s:url tag has been explained [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/url.html) and there are a lot of online examples for it. Also if you use get method for the form you can use s:hidden tags.